# How can I use Tasks correctly?

Tags: c#, task

```
private async Task<List<PingReply>> PingAsync()
{
    Ping pingSender = new Ping();
    var tasks = serverNames.Select(ip => pingSender.SendPingAsync(ip, 2000));
    var results = await Task.WhenAll(tasks);

    return results.ToList();
}
```

My question is how would I execute this method?

I've tried

```
 List<string> data = PingAsync();
```

But I get this error message

```
Error   CS0029  Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Threading.Tasks.Task<System.Collections.Generic.List<System.Net.NetworkInformation.PingReply>>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.List<string>' ServerManager
```

I am trying to ping servers and update the UI so we can monitor servers.

I've also tried these

```
        Task<PingReply> longRunningTask = PingAsync();
        PingReply result = await longRunningTask;
```

Error

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
>   Error CS4033  The 'await' operator can only be used within an async
>   method. Consider marking this method with the 'async' modifier and
>   changing its return type to 'Task'.   ServerManager
>
> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
>   Error CS0029  Cannot implicitly convert type
>   'System.Threading.Tasks.Task>'
>   to
>   'System.Threading.Tasks.Task'    ServerManager

Comment: You need to await that method `List<string> data = await PingAsync();`

Comment: I think you should try to understand the error message because as written this cannot possibly work. You will need to understand this sooner or later anyway.

Comment: You might find this useful https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh191443.aspx

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Look at your `PingAsync` method signature. What does it return? `Task<List<PingReply>>`. Adding `async` keyword does not change that type, let's say that it basically allows you to use `await` inside the method.

So, by calling `PingAsync`, you get an object of type `Task<List<PingReply>>`, and try to assign it to a `List<string>` reference - which gives you a type mismatch error.

But, you might ask, how to get an actual `T` form `Task<T>`? You should simply use `await`, just like you do inside your method where you call `Task.WhenAll`.

`List<PingReply> data = await PingAsync();`

Comment: Thank you for the insight. But if I am executing from a private void method, I get an error saying "await" operatior can only be used within an asyn method

Comment: `async` might be sometimes confusing... basically, you should never use `async void` methods (with an exception for event handlers). So, you should most probably change your `async void fooAsync()` to `async Task fooAsync()`.

Comment: Could he also do ``data = PingAsync().Result;`` Why/why not? What would be the difference to using await?

Comment: @codeape See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27464287/what-is-the-difference-betweek-await-taskt-and-taskt-result

Comment: I did that data = PingAsync().Result and the app crashes saying ArguementException was unhandled. The inner message says "{"Value cannot be null.\r\nParameter name: source"}"

Answer (score 1):

The error message by itself is pretty clear. The method signature returns a `Task<List<PingReply>>`, yet for some reason you expect it to return a `List<string>` or `Task<PingReply>`, not sure why.

You should note that starting using `async` in your code makes it spread like a plague. This means that higher level methods calling async methods will usually need themselves be `async` and return a `Task` or `Task<T>`.

Answer (score 0):

Given this Async function

```
private async Task<List<PingReply>> PingAsync()
{
    Ping pingSender = new Ping();
    var tasks = serverNames.Select(
            ip => pingSender.SendPingAsync(ip, 2000)
    );
    var results = await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
    return results.ToList();
}
```

From some other part of the object, call, accepting the TASK wrapped value

```
 Task<List<PingReply>> foo = PingAsync();
```

Then Manually wait it out ...

```
foo.Wait();
```

Then Extract the Value

```
List<PingReply> bar = foo.Result;
```

Comment: More details are needed, this seems like the setup for a question but missing the actual question.