# Inconsistencies with async/await/result using TPL in C#

Tags: c#, multithreading, asynchronous, async-await, task-parallel-library

I've been doing some testing with the TPL in C# to better understand how threads are created and when exactly new threads are kicked off.

With the below tests, The first one, using no `async/await` behaves as expected and always returns the values I would expect.  However, the final 2 tests using `async/await` are very inconsistent.

In my tests, I made the following assumptions:

1. `GetThreadIdInstant` would return on the same thread due to the task being completetd.
2. `GetThreadIdDelayed` would return on a different thread due to the delay not returning instantly.
3. `GetThreadIdForcedNew` would return on a different thread due to the use of `Task.Run()`.

Is there an explanation why the above assumptions are true when using `.Result` on a task, but not consistently true when using `async/await`?

Edit: Clarification on "inconsistent" tests: So the last 2 tests using `async/await`, I still expected them to give the same results as the first test using `.Result`, which is not true.  However, the reason I have the code inside of a `for` loop is that some iterations work, and then later on my `Assert` statement will fail.  The reason I used the word "inconsistent" is b/c continuously running the tests, and alternating between just running them versus debugging them causes them to sometimes pass and sometimes fail.

```
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting;
using System;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Parallels.Tests
{
    [TestClass]
    public class GetterTests
    {
        //this test always succeeds
        [TestMethod]
        public void ResultTest()
        {
            for (var i = 0; i < 500; i++)
            {
                var currentThreadId = Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId;

                var instantThreadId = ThreadGetter.GetThreadIdInstant().Result;
                var delayedThreadId = ThreadGetter.GetThreadIdDelayed().Result;
                var forcedNewThreadId = ThreadGetter.GetThreadIdForcedNew().Result;

                Assert.AreEqual(currentThreadId, instantThreadId);
                Assert.AreNotEqual(currentThreadId, delayedThreadId);
                Assert.AreNotEqual(currentThreadId, forcedNewThreadId);
            }
        }

        //mixed results
        [TestMethod]
        public async Task AwaitDelayedTest()
        {

            for (var i = 0; i < 500; i++)
            {
                try
                {
                    var currentThreadId = Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId;

                    var delayedThreadId = await ThreadGetter.GetThreadIdDelayed();

                    Assert.AreNotEqual(currentThreadId, delayedThreadId);
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    throw new Exception($"failed at iteration: {i}", ex);
                }
            }

        }

        //mixed results
        [TestMethod]
        public async Task AwaitForcedNewTest()
        {
            for (var i = 0; i < 500; i++)
            {
                try
                {
                    var currentThreadId = Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId;

                    var forcedNewThreadId = await ThreadGetter.GetThreadIdForcedNew();

                    Assert.AreNotEqual(currentThreadId, forcedNewThreadId);
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    throw new Exception($"failed at iteration: {i}", ex);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public static class ThreadGetter
    {
        public static async Task<int> GetThreadIdInstant() => Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId;

        public static async Task<int> GetThreadIdDelayed()
        {
            await Task.Delay(1);
            return Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId;
        }

        public static async Task<int> GetThreadIdForcedNew() => await Task.Run(() => Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);
    }
}
```

Comment: It would really help if you'd explain exactly what you mean by "very inconsistent". It's hard to explain results without knowing what those results are.

Comment: Also I think you mean [TAP](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh873175(v=vs.110).aspx), not [TPL](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460717(v=vs.110).aspx).  Nothing in your question appears to be TPL-specific.

Comment: I tried to give more clarification on what I meant by "inconsistent".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27466042/2876968) to a related question here.

When you use .Result... you are blocking the current thread, and thus work done on the tasks in your GetThreadIdDelayed() and GetThreadIdForcedNew() methods *always* runs in a thread other than the calling thread.

When you use await... Although execution does not continue on the calling thread, that thread is not consumed during the execution of the subtasks, and may (sometimes) be used to do the work of some of the subtasks themselves.

Also note that execution after a call to await does not always return on the same thread by default. This is especially important, for example, in many UI applications. You can control this behavior using [ConfigureAwait](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.task.configureawait(v=vs.110).aspx).