# Using foreach statement on variables of type 'Task<List<SharepointDTO.RootObject>>

Tags: c#, api

I am trying to call the Sharepoint API multiple times in a C# application and storing the returned results in to a `List` like below

```
  private async Task<List<sDTO.RootObject>> getfromSharepoint()
    {
       List<SharepointDTO.RootObject> returnObj = new List<SharepointDTO.RootObject>();
       var result = new UpdateCoreStrains.SharepointDTO.RootObject();
        ......
        // Calling GET Sharepoint Site
        try
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < 10000; i = i + 5000)
            {
                SP_StrainCodes = "GetByTitle('S%20Codes')/items?$skiptoken=Paged=TRUE%26p_ID=" + i + "&$top=1";
                core_URL = BaseURL_SP + SP_StrainCodes;

                var response = client_sharePoint.GetAsync(core_URL).Result;
                var responsedata = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                 result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<sDTO.RootObject>(responsedata);
                    if (result.d.Next == null)
                        continue;

                }
                returnObj.Add(result);
            }
            return returnObj;
        }
```

Now I am calling getfromSharepoint() in other function and I want to iterate over the List to validate the data

```
    public List<numberList>  getListFromSharepoint()
    {
        List<umberList> nums = new List<numberList>();
        try
        {

            Task<List<sDTO.RootObject>> sharepointList = getfromSharepoint();

            foreach(sDTO retSharepointobj in sharepointList)
            {

                if (retSharepointobj == null ||
                    retSharepointobj.Id == 0 ||
                    retSharepointobj.Result.
                    retSharepointobj.Result == null ||
                    retSharepointobj.Result.d == null ||
                    retSharepointobj.Result.d.results == null ||
                    retSharepointobj.Result.d.results.Count == 0
                    )
                {
                    return nums;  // count = 0, return an empty list
                }
```

But I am getting an error like

`foreach statement cannot operate on variables of type 'Task<List<SharepointDTO.RootObject>>' because 'Task<List<SharepointDTO.RootObject>>' does not contain a public definition for 'GetEnumerator'` How can I iterate over >

Comment: You have async code, you should be `await`ing it properly.

Comment: @DavidG Yeah doing  `var responsedata = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();`

Comment: try this `Task<List<sDTO.RootObject>> sharepointList = await getfromSharepoint();` and make `getListFromSharepoint` method as `async`

Comment: how you call this method from other function `getListFromSharepoint()`;

Answer (score 1):

Try to make your `getListFromSharepoint` method as `async`.

```
 public async Task<List<numberList>> getListFromSharepoint()
    {
        List<umberList> nums = new List<numberList>();
        try
        {
            //Here we use an await to get result from getfromSharepoint() method call.
            List<sDTO.RootObject> sharepointList = await getfromSharepoint();

            foreach (sDTO retSharepointobj in sharepointList)
            {
                //your rest of code is same here
            }
```

**Edit:**

And from other function call `getListFromSharepoint` method as

```
List<numberList> result = await getListFromSharepoint();
```

**OR**

You could simply use `Result` of `getfromSharepoint`.

```
List<sDTO.RootObject> sharepointList = await getfromSharepoint().Result;
```

Comment: With the change `sharepointList`  shouldn't be of type `Task`, it will now be a plain `List<sDTO.RootObject>`. Also, [throw ex; is a bad practice](https://stackoverflow.com/q/730250/2557263), there is no reason to have try/catch here at all.

Comment: try/catch and throw ex is only for completing curly brackets. thank for suggestion i'll update my answer

Comment: @ershoaib I am getting Error like `Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.List<UpdateCoreStrains.SharepointDTO.RootObject>' to 'System.Threading.Tasks.Task<System.Collections.Generic.List<UpdateCoreStrains.SharepointDTO.RootObject>>'` If i am using `Task<List<SharepointDTO.RootObject>> returnSharepointList = await getfromSharepoint()`

Comment: where did u get this error `from calling function` of from `getListFromSharepoint`?

Comment: what you get if only with `Task<List<sDTO.RootObject>> sharepointList = getfromSharepoint().Result;`?

Comment: As per my first comment, the line `Task<List<sDTO.RootObject>> sharepointList = await getfromSharepoint();` is still broken. The return value is *not* a `Task`, that's consumed by the `await`. Change it to `List<sDTO.RootObject> sharepointList = await getfromSharepoint();` instead.

Answer (score 0):

Ths: `Task<List<sDTO.RootObject>> sharepointList = getfromSharepoint();` is calling an `async` method, which doesn't return immediately. Your code should look something like so:

```
List<sDTO.RootObject> sharepointList = getfromSharepoint().Result;
```

Comment: List<sDTO.RootObject> sharepointList = getfromSharepoint().Result; This shouldn't be a option it will break the normal flow of async function.

Comment: @Eldho: Actually, I cannot use `await`, since the calling method is not `async` itself.

Comment: Calling `.Results` on a `Task` is an easy way to get into deadlocks and should be avoided, use `await` instead. Have a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/27464287/2557263

Answer (score 0):

Here you are trying to iterate over items of `sharepointList` which is of type `Task` which does not contain a public definition for 'GetEnumerator'(As the error message stated). But you can Iterate over the Result of Task since its a collection of `RootObject`. If you are looking for looping through `List<sDTO.RootObject>` of `sharepointList` you should use :

```
foreach (sDTO.RootObject retSharepointobj in sharepointList.Result)
{
   // here each retSharepointobj  of type RootObject 
   // code here
}
```