# Add Method returns null empty object to database

Tags: c#, .net

I've got data from an API, deserializing it to work with my model, but when I try to add that data to my database its only stores a blank object.I've tried passing through CrdResponse but that provides an exception that I can't get around.

```
public async Task <ActionResult> InsertCard(Card card)
        {

            List<Card> CardsInfo = new List<Card>();

            var getUrl = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.AbsoluteUri;

            var test = new Uri(getUrl);

            var id = test.Segments.Last();

            SingleResult += id;


            using (var client = new HttpClient())
            {
                //passing service baseurl 
                client.BaseAddress = new Uri(SingleResult);

                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Clear();

                //Define request data format
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

                //Sending request to find web api REST service resource Getallcards using HTTPClient
                HttpResponseMessage Res = await client.GetAsync(SingleResult);

                //Checking the response is successful or not which is sent using HttpClient  

                if (Res.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                {
                    //Storing the response details received from web api

                    var CrdResponse = Res.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;


                    //Deserializing the response recieved from web api and storing in to the card list
                    CardsInfo = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Card>>(CrdResponse);

                    _context.Cards.Add(card);

                    _context.SaveChanges();
                }

            }

            return RedirectToAction("Index", "API");
        }
```

and my Model

```
 public class Card
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public int? Atk { get; set; }
        public int? Def { get; set; }
        public string Desc {get; set;}
        public int? Level { get; set; }
        public string Type { get; set; }
        public string Attribute { get; set; }
        [DisplayName("Image")]
        public IList<Image> Card_Images { get; set; }

        public IList<Deck> Deck { get; set; }
    }
```

EDIT: CrdResponse contains:

```
[{"id":"11714098","name":"30,000-Year White Turtle","type":"Normal Monster","desc":"A huge turtle that has existed for more than 30,000 years.","atk":"1250","def":"2100","level":"5","race":"Aqua","attribute":"WATER","card_images":[{"id":"11714098","image_url":"https://storage.googleapis.com/ygoprodeck.com/pics/11714098.jpg","image_url_small":"https://storage.googleapis.com/ygoprodeck.com/pics_small/11714098.jpg"}],"card_prices":{"cardmarket_price":"0.00","tcgplayer_price":"0.00","ebay_price":"10.0","amazon_price":"0.00"}}]
```

which is all the info i am hoping to pull through

Comment: Also what is the error

Comment: So, did you put a breakpoint there to see why `card` is empty? I cannot see you *using* the reply from the webservice anywhere, might that be the reason?

Comment: When i try to use Cards Info The error is  Argument 1: cannot convert from 'System.Collections.Generic.List<YGOBuilder.Models.Card>' to 'YGOBuilder.Models.Card' YGOBuilder

Comment: Seems like you getting a single vlaue and you trying to deserialize into a list, the line `CardsInfo = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Card>>(CrdResponse);` is where your erro occurs, try making it as `CardsInfo = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Card>(CrdResponse);`

Comment: It pulls correctly when I call the same method to display all results, so i assume it is correct otherwise it would not work for the index method i use.

Comment: So, you store the deserialized API call result into `CardsInfo`, but add `card` in your context. Your `CardsInfo` variable is not used anywhere and your `card` object is passed as the method parameter and not used at all until you add it to the context.

Comment: Obligatory: https://aspnetmonsters.com/2016/08/2016-08-27-httpclientwrong/ and https://josefottosson.se/you-are-probably-still-using-httpclient-wrong-and-it-is-destabilizing-your-software/ and https://stackoverflow.com/a/27466042/3312

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are adding the 'Card' you pass through in the method parameter:

```
public async Task <ActionResult> InsertCard(Card card)
...
_context.Cards.Add(card);
```

I think what you want to do is pass through the card you are deserialising from the string response:

```
CardsInfo = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Card>>(CrdResponse);

foreach(Card c in CardsInfo)
{
    _context.Cards.Add(c);
}
```

Comment: This is actually quite close however for some reason the card ID does not accept the ID that comes through the JSON. but rather increments in the database.

Comment: Question - does the `Card` already exist in the database - in that case you want to update it not add it, if not then your database design is wrong - you have an auto-incrementing key when you do not want one.

Comment: no the card does not already exist, i am calling the api and adding a new object in the database based from the values in the api response

Comment: Then you need to change the database ID column to allow inserts. This will vary depending on the type of database you are using.

Comment: @AndyStav You need to configure your database not to generate ID automatically. Take a look at [generated values](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/generated-properties). `[DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]` attribute on your `Id` property of `Card` class could do the job (or using fluent API as shown in the article).

Comment: amazing, thank you all so much this has been so helpful and i've learned loads! closing the question

Answer (score -2):

You forgot to await the result of the ReadAsStringAsync method, like so:

```
var CrdResponse = await Res.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
```

As it is an async method it might not have completed the operation when you call result, that depends on the size of the string you are trying to read.

Hope to have helped!

Comment: This guy's response shouldn't have the downvotes it has. `.Result` is a big no-no in general, and ESPECIALLY in a method which is already properly marked as `async` and `await`s other calls. This is a right change that needs to be made.