# HttpResponseMessage' does not contain a definition for 'GetAwaiter' and no accessible extension method 'GetAwaiter'

Tags: c#, async-await

I have this xUnit method in C# which test a web api

```
    [Fact]
    public async Task GetWeatherForecast()
    {
        var apiClient = new HttpClient();

        var apiResponse = await apiClient.GetAsync($"http://xxx/weatherforecast").Result;

        Assert.True(apiResponse.IsSuccessStatusCode);
    }
```

But hit this error `HttpResponseMessage' does not contain a definition for 'GetAwaiter' and no accessible extension method 'GetAwaiter'`. If I removed `async Task` and `await`, it could run successfully.

Comment: See related [What is the difference between await Task<T> and Task<T>.Result?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27464287/what-is-the-difference-between-await-taskt-and-taskt-result)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Don't call `Result`, it's likely to cause issues on the best of days when using the *async and await pattern*

```
 var apiResponse = await apiClient.GetAsync($"http://xxx/weatherforecast");
```

However, the problem is because you are trying to use a *language feature* associated with the `await` keywords that requires an *awaitable*. The compiler dictates that to `await` something it must satisfy certain constraints. An *awaitable* must  implement the `GetAwaiter` method, `INotifyCompletion`, `IsCompleted` and `GetResult` method. Which is what the error message is describing.

This is due to the fact you have called the `Result<T>` method which returns the result value of a *task* (in this case the result from the Task returned from `GetAsync<Task<T>>`, your `HttpResponseMessage`). You are then trying to `await` it like it is a *task* / *awaitable*, which it is not.

In general, there are very few cases in the modern-era where calling `Result`, or `Wait` is actually a good idea.

Comment: i m not calling the Result like that   `List<ExportInspectionWears> GetInspectionlist = await inspection_Manager.getInspectionDetailsByDistributor_LatestIns(dLastProcessDate.ToString(), item.Trim());`  but still getting this error