# Trying to understand Xunit service test in tutorial

Tags: c#, unit-testing, moq, xunit.net

I have been following this [tutorial](https://henriquesd.medium.com/creating-an-application-from-scratch-using-net-core-and-angular-part-6-76daa358db41) and trying to understand this Xunit test for an update service.

The service is as follows:

```
public async Task<Category> Update(Category category)
{
  if (_categoryRepository.Search(c => c.Name == category.Name && c.Id != category.Id).Result.Any())
    return null;

  await _categoryRepository.Update(category);
  return category;
}
```

And the Xunit test:

```
[Fact]
public async void Update_ShouldNotUpdateCategory_WhenCategoryDoesNotExist()
{
  var category = new Category()
  {
    Id = 1,
    Name = "Test Category 1"
  };

  var categoryList = new List<Category>()
  {
    new Category()
    {
        Id = 2,
        Name = "Test Category 2"
    }
  };

  _categoryRepositoryMock.Setup(c => c.Search(c => c.Name == category.Name && c.Id != category.Id))
      .ReturnsAsync(categoryList);

  var result = await _categoryService.Update(category);

  Assert.Null(result);
}
```

I know that from this authors notes about what the test is supposed to do is contradicting what the method name's *when-condition* (It's about 3/4 the way the linked tutorial page):

- The method does not update a category when the updated category name already exists.

The test is returning null, but I'm not sure if it's doing it for the right reason.

Is it that it can't find the category in the mock repo? As I tried adding a category in hopes that it would find the category and fail the test, but it still came back as null:

```
new Category()
{
  Id = 1,
  Name = "Test Category One"
}
```

Or is it that the mocking of the validation which returns categoryListing and even though it is not the correct record (as it's name is not a match) enough to cause the null? (I'm guessing it is this one)

I am new to unit testing, but it doesn't feel like a good test shouldn't the mock repository be preloaded with records and then the updated record have it's validation tested against it? I'm guessing this would just be another way of doing this, however, how would I change the code to accomplish that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The test is returning null, but I'm not sure if it's doing it for the right reason.

You are exactly right - service does not check for existence of the category and test passes only because the mock is setup to mimic behaviour "another category with the same name exists".

> I am new to unit testing, but it doesn't feel like a good test shouldn't the mock repository be preloaded with records and then the updated record have it's validation tested against it

It is one of the approaches - it is matter of preference/best practices what and how to split up and test. I would say that provided code is bad in many parts:

1. The call to `Task.Result` (in `CategoryService.Update`) over async method is considered a bad practice ([read more #1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27464287/what-is-the-difference-between-await-taskt-and-taskt-result), [read more #2](https://tooslowexception.com/the-danger-of-asyncawait-and-result-in-one-picture/)):

```cs
if (_categoryRepository.Search(c => c.Name == category.Name && c.Id != category.Id).Result.Any())
                return null;
```

2. In general repository pattern over EF can be considered as antipattern (but there are a lot of people who will not agree with this), but even if you go with it the implementation of `Update` method still is very questionable
3. Contract relying on returning `null` also seems very questionable.

> I'm guessing this would just be another way of doing this, however, how would I change the code to accomplish that?

First of all you will need to change the `Update` method to check for existence of the record. For example by adding next line:

```cs
if (!(await _categoryRepository.Search(c => c.Id == category.Id)).Any())
    return null;
```

(though I would combine both `Search` calls to `_categoryRepository.Search(c => c.Name == category.Name || c.Id != category.Id)` and checked the search results for count and existence of record with corresponding Id)

And then update the test by adding extra `Setup` call (other test can also require `Setup` update):

```
_categoryRepositoryMock.Setup(c => c.Search(c => c.Id == category.Id))
    .ReturnsAsync(new List<Category> {  });
```

Comment: thank you! I was going crazy not understanding, most of this makes sense straight off the bat. When you say 'combine both Search calls' I understand it is more efficient but doesn't that make it trickier to test the two validations separately, or is that even though you have combined the Search you may still do two separate Setups for the validations?

Comment: Also, if I do want to try preloading the mock repository with a dataset how would you code this?

Comment: @Hank _"I understand it is more efficient but doesn't that make it trickier to test the two validations separately"_ - I would say not by much, you can easily manipulate collection returned from mock, so it should not be (only one setup needed). _"if I do want to try preloading the mock repository with a dataset"_ - you can setup mock which will use the same collection for different calls. Also one of the most popular approaches is to use [in-memory database provider](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/providers/in-memory/?tabs=dotnet-core-cli)