# Running two taks parallely in C#

Tags: c#, hash, parallel-processing

I need to compute hashes of two big files (around 10GB) to check for equality. Currently i'm computing one hash at a time, but to save a lot of time i had the idea to parallely compute both hashes at the same time.
Heres my method:

```
private bool checkEquality(FileInfo firstFile, FileInfo secondFile)
{
    //These 2 lines are for creating one hash at a time, currently commented out for 
    //testing purpose
    //byte[] firstHash = createHash(firstFile);
    //byte[] secondHash = createHash(secondFile);

    //My take in running the computing processes parallely
    Task<byte[]> fh = Task.Run(() => createHash(firstFile));
    Task<byte[]> sh = Task.Run(() => createHash(secondFile));

    byte[] firstHash = fh.Result;
    byte[] secondHash = sh.Result;

    for (int i = 0; i < firstHash.Length; i++)
    {
        if (firstHash[i] != secondHash[i]) return false;
    }           
    return true;        
}
```

Since this is my first time trying to do something like that, i'm not quite sure if the code i wrote does work as i imagine, because i've seen usual use of async methods in combination with the await keyword in other threads, but i cant wrap my head about this concept yet.

Edit:
Ok i changed my method to:

```
private async Task<bool> checkEquality(FileInfo firstFile, FileInfo secondFile)
{
    //These 2 lines are for creating one hash at a time, currently commented out for 
    //testing purpose
    //byte[] firstHash = createHash(firstFile);
    //byte[] secondHash = createHash(secondFile);

    //My take in running the computing processes parallely
    Task<byte[]> fh = Task.Run(() => createHash(firstFile));
    Task<byte[]> sh = Task.Run(() => createHash(secondFile));

    byte[] firstHash = await fh;
    byte[] secondHash = await sh;

    for (int i = 0; i < firstHash.Length; i++)
    {
        if (firstHash[i] != secondHash[i]) return false;
    }           
    return true;        
}
```

Is this the working way to run both computing processes asynchronously at the same time?

Comment: Do not use `.Result`. Await async Tasks.

Comment: [What is the difference between `await Task<T>` and `Task<T>.Result`?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27464287)

Comment: In fact, I think you could have been using Parallel.ForEach, here with less hassle.

Comment: Are both files stored in the same physical storage? If yes, what is the type of the storage? SSD? Classic hard disk?

Comment: [Gigantor](https://github.com/imagibee/Gigantor) has a DuplicateChecker class that does equality comparison of files on disk rather quickly.  But if you need the hashes too it won't do that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `Task.WhenAll` to run both tasks and await them finishing.

```
var result = await Task.WhenAll(fh, sh);
byte[] firstHash = result[0];
byte[] secondHash = result[1];
```

Answer (score 0):

This is an appropriate usage for actual parallel code; it's CPU-bound and not, e.g., I/O-bound which is more appropriate for `async`/`await`.

I recommend using the higher-level APIs such as `Parallel` or PLINQ for parallel code. In this case, PLINQ will work nicely:

```
private bool checkEquality(FileInfo firstFile, FileInfo secondFile)
{
  var results = new[] { firstFile, secondFile }
      .AsParallel()
      .Select(createHash)
      .ToList();

  return results[0].AsSpan().SequenceEqual(results[1]);
}
```

Comment: Caution, the `results[0]` might not be the hash of the `firstFile`, because the [`AsOrdered`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.parallelenumerable.asordered) has not been used. In this specific case it doesn't matter though.