# Convert from XML response to list

Tags: c#, xml, list, .net-core, xml-deserialization

```cs
XElement Xml = null;
var apiResponse = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
Xml = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<XElement>(apiResponse);
```

XML response from the above code:

I'm having errors with `Images` XML part while converting it to List,
I tried so many options, please provide suggestion below:

```
<root>
  <Column1>
    <ID>2702</ID>
    <Desc>Failed</Desc>
    <Address>Florida</Address>
    <Date>2019-04-30T23:10:36.79</Date>
    <Images>
      <Image>
        <File>1-RRamos.PNG</File>
      </Image>
      <Image>
        <File>RRamos.PNG</File>
      </Image>
      <Image>
        <File>3-RRamos.PNG</File>
      </Image>
    </Images>
  </Column1>
</root>
```

Trying to convert from XML to List as below:

```cs
public class objClass
{
    public string ID { get; set; }
    public string Desc { get; set; }
    public string Address { get; set; }
    public DateTime? Date { get; set; }

    //public string[] ImageFileNames { get; set; }

    public List<Images> FileName { get; set; }
}

public class Images
{
    public string File { get; set; }
}

List<objClass> list = Xml.Elements("ID").Select(sv => new objClass()
{
    ID = (string)sv.Element("ID"),
    Desc = (string)sv.Element("Desc"),
    Address = (string)sv.Element("Address"),
    Date = (DateTime?)sv.Element("Date"),
    //**,Images = (List)sv.Element("Images")**
}).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```cs
public class objClass
{
    public string ID { get; set; }
    public string Desc { get; set; }
    public string Address { get; set; }
    public DateTime? Date { get; set; }
    public string[] ImageFileNames { get; set; }
}

var list = Xml.Elements("root").Elements("Column1")
.Select(sv => new objClass()
{
    ID = (string)sv.Element("ID"),
    Desc = (string)sv.Element("Desc"),
    Address = (string)sv.Element("Address"),
    Date = (DateTime?)sv.Element("Date"),
    ImageFileNames = sv.Element("Images")
        .Elements("Image")
        .Select(i => (string)i.Element("File"))
        .ToArray(),
})
.ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't use the *Newtonsoft.Json* library to deserialize from an XML.

**Solution 1: Convert XML to list via XPath**

1. Parse XML string to `XDocument`.
2. With XPath: "//root/Column1", select the `<Column1>` element.

```cs
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;
using System.Xml.Serialization;
using System.Xml.XPath;

var apiResponse = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
XDocument @Xml = XDocument.Parse(apiResponse);
        
List<ObjClass> list = @Xml.XPathSelectElements("//root/Column1")
    .Select(sv => new ObjClass()
            {
                ID = (string)sv.Element("ID"),
                Desc = (string)sv.Element("Desc"),
                Address = (string)sv.Element("Address"),
                Date = (DateTime?)sv.Element("Date"),
                Images = sv.Element("Images")
                    .Elements("Image")
                    .Select(x => new Image
                            {
                                File = (string)x.Element("File")
                            })
                    .ToList()   
            })
    .ToList();
```

---

**Solution 2: Deserialize XML**

This answer will be a bit complex but work the same as *Solution 1*.

1. Write the `apiResponse` value into `MemoryStream`.
2. Deserialize the `MemoryStream` via `XmlSerializer` as `Root`.
3. Extract `root.Column` and add into `list`.

```cs
[XmlRoot(ElementName = "root")]
public class Root
{
    [XmlElement("Column 1")]
    public ObjClass Column { get; set; }
}

public class ObjClass
{
    public string ID { get; set; }

    public string Desc { get; set; }

    public string Address { get; set; }

    public DateTime? Date { get; set; }

    [XmlArray]
    [XmlArrayItem(typeof(Image), ElementName = "Image")]
    public List<Image> Images { get; set; }
}

public class Image
{
    public string File { get; set; }
}
```

```cs
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Serialization;
using System.IO;

var apiResponse = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

using var stream = new MemoryStream();
using var writer = new StreamWriter(stream);
writer.Write(apiResponse);
writer.Flush();
stream.Position = 0;
        
XmlSerializer xmlSerializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Root));      
        
Root root = (Root)xmlSerializer.Deserialize(stream);
List<ObjClass> list = new List<ObjClass>();
list.Add(root.Column);
```

Concern:

1. Use `await` instead of `Task<T>.Result` as `Task<T>.Result` will block the calling thread until it (the task) is completed. With `await`, the task is waited to be completed asynchronously. Reference: [What is the difference between await Task and Task.Result?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27464287/what-is-the-difference-between-await-taskt-and-taskt-result)

Comment: [Demo Solution 1 @ .NET Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/41xGRk)

Comment: [Demo Solution 2 @ .NET Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/lbBT07)

Comment: You missed [LINQ to XML](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/standard/linq/linq-xml-overview). 